# Linq query to get count with multiple column values coming from condition on another column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table A as below:

Table A

```
ID  ScheduleID     UserCode

1        4              D
2        4              A  
3        1              B   
4        2              D  
5        4              C   
6        6              A    
7        2              B
```

I want to get count of rows for all those scheduleID values that corresponds to a specific UserCode. e.g., for UserCode = D, corresponding ScheduleIDs are 4 & 2. Count of all rows with ScheduleID = 2 & 4  is 5.

I have tried following query:

```
int count = A.Count(j => j.ScheduleID.Equals  
   (A.Any(k => k.UserCode == D)));
```

This gives run-time error

> "Unable to cast the type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Object'

. Can anyone suggest what should be the accurate query for this scenario?

Comment: you are comparing J.ScheduleID (which is a number) to a boolean. .Any() returns a boolean to indicate if there is any matches to your query

Comment: @GerriePretorius You are right. Can u suggest how should I find this count. I have tried different options but could not work out. I am new to Linq. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = A.Where(p=> p.UserCode == D).Select(x=> x.ScheduleID);
var count = A.Count(p=> query.Contains(p.ScheduleID));
```

you can replace query in the second line probably with the top line, to make it one line, but i Personaly think this is cleaner

Comment: You might want to do a ToList() on the query so it only runs through it once. Else it'll run for every line in A in the second line of code.

Comment: @STDMP actually you don't want to do that, by leaving it like this, it stays an iqueryable and will then execute on the SQL as one query even though you have written 2 queries in c#, by doing a ToList() on the query, it will do 2 database calls. bring back the results of query, only to send it of again on the next query back to the database.

Comment: @GerriePretorius I didn't get the 2 db calls thing. -could you give me an example in this scenario. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution to get the same result :

```
        int count = (from q1 in A
                     join q2 in A on q1.ScheduleID equals q2.ScheduleID
                     where q2.UserCode == "D"
                     select q1).Count();
```